# Existence of projections within $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

I am working on a problem and one of the intermediate steps I want to prove is that in a unital $C^*$-algebra, given a selfadjoint element $x$, there exists a non-trivial projection $y \in \mathcal{A}_x$, where $\mathcal{A}_x$ denotes the $C^*$-algebra generated by $x$. If not mistaken, one has an isometric $^*$-isomorphism
$$
\Psi: \mathcal{A}_x \rightarrow \mathcal{C}(\sigma(x)),
$$
which let's me believe there has to be such element given a disconnected spectrum. Still, I fail to see how a mere algebra guarantees such existence.

I am curious also if such existence is conditional also on the general $C^*$-algebra, i.e. existence of a non-trivial projection $e \neq 0,1$ in the bigger algebra implies existence of a projection in other generated subalgebras.

---

I consider the algebra generated by $x$ to be
$$
\mathcal{A}_x = \overline{\{ \sum_{m,n=1}^N \alpha_{m,n}\;x^{m}(x^*)^n : \alpha_{i,j} \in \mathbb{C} \}}
$$

---

In response to the comments, the original problem requires to show that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all projections $a$ in the $C^*$-algebra and $x$ self-adjoint with $\|a - x\| < \delta$, there exists a projection $g \in C(\sigma(x))$ with the property $\|a - \Psi^{-1}(g)| < \varepsilon.$

My initial thought was to first identify the projections of $C(\sigma(x))$ and from there to map them back to the algebra and gain more insight afterwards.

Comment: How do you define the $C^*$-algebra generated by $x$? If you demand it to have the same unit as the $C^*$-algebra, then of course it will have a projection. If you just take the polynomials in $x$ with zero constant coefficient and close it in norm, then you may not have any projections; consider $A=C[0,1]$ and $x$ being the function $f(z)=z$. Generally, having a lot of projections is a property of a von Neumann algebra, not a $C^*$-algebra.

Comment: Judging from your description I suspect you are either misinterpreting something or perhaps missing some important hypothesis.

Comment: A C*-algebra need not have non-zero projections.

Comment: I'm not experienced at this stuff, so I probably don't know what I'm talking about. But it seems like $\Psi^{-1}$ of any characteristic function would be a projection, and $\Psi^{-1}$ of the identity function would be $x$. So you would hope that the identity function is close to a  characteristic function, equivalently that the spectrum of $x$ is contained in a pair of tiny balls about $0$ and $1$.